# How to interact with native UI elements from flutter integration_test?

Tags: flutter, ui-automation, flutter-integration-test

I am trying to do an automated testing of  the user flow in a flutter app.  For this I am using flutter integration test package (https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/integration-tests).  I have written tests using  integration_test package. Though these tests run on a physical device, there are situation where I have to interact with native UI elements (for example, clicking on  a permission button to give permission to camera etc.) However,  I am not able to interact with the native  UI elements specifically :

1.Tapping Allow on System permission dialog
2.Tapping on Capture button when camera is opened
3.Selecting an image from gallery

I would like to understand how the above situations can be achieved through a script and hence automated. Also, can frameworks like appium-flutter-driver or flutter-driver be used in conjunction with flutter_integration to achieve this. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Long story short, it is likely not currently possible.

These two GitHub issues are pretty much our concern:

- [Add support to test native permission dialog](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87440) (#87440)
- [Allow driving native UI interactions from Dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86295) (#86295)

But, so far, every comment about the matter has been a remark about how difficult it is. The only "solution" from the Android side is to use Android ADB—but, at that point, it isn't even an `integration_test` anymore.